# puppeteer using queryselector from elementhandle

Tags: xpath, css-selectors, puppeteer

I have element handle that are result from this xpath

```
var theXpath = await page.$x(
  "//div[contains(@class, 'fontBodyMedium')]"
)
```

how would i run queryselector

```
"div > div > span > span:nth-of-type(2)"
```

inside that elementhandle and then get the innerHTML of the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently i can just use $eval

```
var theXpath = await page.$x(
  "//div[contains(@class, 'fontBodyMedium')]"
)
for (let index = 0; index < theXpath.length; index++) {
  const inner_html = await theXpath[index].$eval(
    "div > div > span > span:nth-of-type(2)",
    (element) => element.innerHTML
  )
}
```